# The package zhnumber without xeCJK

Tags: macros, counters, cjk, xecjk

I need to use the function `zhdigits` from the package `zhnumber` to typeset a counter the way I want, i.e. convert 235 to 二三五.  This package requires the package `xeCJK` to work properly, but `xeCJK` messes up my quotation marks, so I would rather not use it.

Is it possible to implement `zhdigits` without `xeCJK`?  That is, implement a fuction that converts a string of charaters to another string of characters according to the below mapping:

```
1 ↦ 一
2 ↦ 二
3 ↦ 三
4 ↦ 四
5 ↦ 五
6 ↦ 六
7 ↦ 七
8 ↦ 八
9 ↦ 九
0 ↦ 〇
```

Comment: Are you using XeLaTeX? For old `CJK` package for Chinese support, you can use `CJKnumb` package.

Comment: @LeoLiu Yes, I am using XeLaTeX.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can define a couple of macros; here I used `\zhnumber` for typesetting in Chinese numerals any explicit (whole) number, while `\zhdigits` takes as argument the name of a counter, analogously to `\arabic`, `\Roman` and so on. I've also used it for `\pagenumbering`, just to show it works.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\newfontfamily{\zhfont}{Songti SC}
\DeclareTextFontCommand{\textzh}{\zhfont}

\makeatletter
\def\zhdigits#1{\expandafter\@zhdigits\csname c@#1\endcsname}
\def\@zhdigits#1{\expandafter\textzh\expandafter{\expandafter\@slowzhdigits\number#1@}}
\def\zhnumber#1{\textzh{\@slowzhdigits#1@}}
\def\@slowzhdigits#1{%
  \ifx @#1% terminate
  \else
    \if0#1〇\else\if1#1一\else\if2#1二\else\if3#1三\else\if4#1四%
    \else\if5#1五\else\if6#1六\else\if7#1七\else\if8#1八\else\if9#1九%
    \fi\fi\fi\fi\fi\fi\fi\fi\fi\fi
    \expandafter\@slowzhdigits
  \fi}
\makeatother

\pagenumbering{zhdigits}

\textheight=6cm % just to show the page number at the bottom

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\section{Test}

\zhnumber{0123456789876543210}

\textzh{〇一二三四五六七八九八七六五四三二一〇}


\textzh{一二〇}

\setcounter{page}{120}
\zhdigits{page}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Wow, this is just what I wanted.  Finally, I can typset Chinese pagenumbering!  This should become a standard LaTeX feature.

Answer (score 3):

If you use raw XeTeX or LuaTeX, here is a very simple implementation:

```
\documentclass{article}

\makeatletter
% The argument is not expanded
\def\zhdigits#1{%
  \@tfor\next:=#1\do{%
    \ifcase\next
      〇\or 一\or 二\or 三\or 四\or 五\or 六\or 七\or 八\or 九%
    \fi}}
% The argument is expanded first
\def\zhdigitx#1{%
  \edef\next{#1}%
  \expandafter\zhdigits\expandafter{\next}}
\makeatother

\font\song="SimSun"

\begin{document}

\song

\zhdigits{0123456789876543210}
% 〇一二三四五六七八九八七六五四三二一〇

\setcounter{page}{120}
第\zhdigitx{\arabic{page}}页

\end{document}
```

For old `CJK` package, just use `\CJKdigits` from `CJKnumb` package.

Anyway, I wonder why `xeCJK` cannot be used here. Maybe we can figure out a better solution.

Comment: I think, this is what I asked for, but not what I needed.  I thought I could convert a counter to Chinese in this way, but `\zhdigits{\arabic{page}}` gives an error.  Is it possible to modify the function to convert a counter to a string of Chinese numbers?

Comment: @user25750: See my update.

Comment: @user25750: `xeCJK` is still preferrable for long CJK text. For quotation marks, just use old TeX form `\``, `'` and `\`\``, `''` instead of `‘`, `’` and `“`, `”`.

Comment: This implementation also works.  Thanks!  @LeoLiu The main text is in a Latin based script, so I prefer Latin quotation marks. It's better when the symbols you type is the symbols you get.  For pure Chinese, I guess that `xeCJK` would be preferable.